# Titletoc package adds all the contents

Tags: sectioning, titlesec

When I use \startcontents and \printcontents the "partial" ToC added all the contents in the .out file although I use \stopcontents. They are added like inline text and the sections that are suppose to appear are the only ones that appear with section number and the page.

[image]

The code is:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{book}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[pdfborder={0 0 0}]{hyperref}
\usepackage{titletoc}

\title{University}
\author{Me}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents

\part{\label{part:1}Part I}

    \chapter{\label{chap:1.1}Chapter 1}

    \chapter{\label{chap:1.2}Chapter 2}
        \startcontents[chapterTwo]
        \printcontents[chapterTwo]{}{1}{}

        \section{\label{sect:1.2.1}Section 1}

        \section{\label{sect:1.2.2}Section 2}

        \stopcontents[chapterTwo]

    \chapter{\label{chap:1.3}Chapter 3}

        \section{Section 1}

        \section{Section 2}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! It's  hard to say from a screenshot… Could you post a small compilable code  which reproduces the problem?